# Is the Matrix Diagonalizable if $A^2=4I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

I have two question:

> Let $A$ be a non-scalar matrix, $A_{k \times k} \in \Bbb R$, and $A^2=4I$. **Is the matrix A, always diagonalizable in $\Bbb R$?**
>
> Answer

I know that the answer is **yes**:

$$A^2=4I \rightarrow A^2-4I=0$$

Then by the Cayley Hamilton theorem I know that the matrix satisfies the equation above.

Now I don't know how to explain the fact that the characteristic polynomial is $P_A=(\lambda-2)(\lambda+2)$, then the characteristic polynomial has two different roots, and no more. what's the reason for it?

**Second Question - Irrelevant to the first question**

When we say that a matrix is diagonalizable if it has different linear roots, it means that for if I have the following characteristic polynomial (for example) $(t-1)^2(t-2)$ then the matrix is not diagonalizable since the root 1 appears twice in the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: If we are to be strict, the answer is **yes**, not **true**.

Comment: Is $k=2$? The characteristic polynomial has degree $k$.

Comment: Your explanation of the answer is not correct. As $A^2-AI=0$, you know that the matrix is a root of the polynomial $X^2-4$, so that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $X^2-4$. Cayley-Hamilton has nothing to do with this.

Comment: $ A^2-4I=0$ means that the chracterisctic polynomial is $\lambda^2-4= (\lambda-2)(\lambda+2)=0$

Comment: @EmilioNovati, no, it does not.

Comment: The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, but not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: YES !!! my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

1. There are only two roots since a polynomial of degree $n$ has exactly $n$ roots (in $\mathbb{C}$). Here, $n=2$, so there are only $2$ roots.
2. The statement in your second question is not correct. For example, consider the identity matrix of dimension $n$. Clearly the identity matrix is diagonalizable (as it is diagonal), but it has characteristic polynomial $(t-1)^n$.

Comment: Maybe the second statement is true for the minimal polynomial? I think I was confused.

Comment: @Alan Yes, it is true for the minimal polynomial, but not for the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $A$ is a root of the polynomial $t^2-4$, hence the *minimal* polynomial of $A$, a divisor of $t^2-4$, has only simple roots. This is is equivalent to $A$ being diagonalisable.

*Answer to the second question:* a matrix over a field $K$ is diagonalisable over $K$ if and only if its minimal polynomial splits  over $K$ into a product of distinct linear factors.

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to answer without using the minimal and characteristic polynomials.

Consider the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of $A$,
$$
A = Q J Q^t,
$$
with $Q$ orthogonal, and split $J$ into its diagonal part $D$ plus its strictly upper triangular part $U$, namely
$$
J = D + U.
$$
Then,
$$
4I = A^2 = Q J Q^t QJ Q^t = Q J^2 Q^t \Longrightarrow J^2 = 4 I.
$$
Exploiting the splitting, we obtain
$$
4I = (D + U)(D+U) = D^2 + DU + UD + U^2.
$$
Notice that $D^2$ is diagonal, whereas $DU + UD + U^2$ is upper triangular, with zeros on the main diagonal. Hence, 
$$
D^2 = 4I \Longrightarrow D = \pm2I.
$$
Moreover, the upper triangular part of $4I$ is zero, hence
$$
0 = DU + UD + U^2 = \pm 4 U + U^2 = U ( U \pm 4 I).
$$
This is possible only for $U = 0$.